# Virtual machine manager error (did not find USB device)

Tags: usb, virtualization

Virtual machine manager on QEMU/KVM don't load windows 10 guest.

Shows this message:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: Did not find USB device 4e8:3413


Details:
Error starting domain: internal error: Did not find USB device 4e8:3413

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 90, in cb_wrapper
callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 126, in tmpcb
callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 83, in newfn
ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1402, in startup
self._backend.create()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1035, in create
if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: internal error: Did not find USB device 4e8:3413
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved

So this is how I got it fixed:

virsh edit `<vmname>` # brings up emacs (or vim for the really smart people) with the xml for the vm

```
-- added  startupPolicy='optional' to the <source> line as below

  <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
       <source startupPolicy='optional'>
         <vendor id='0x03f0'/>
         <product id='0x4217'/>
       </source>
     </hostdev>
```